# How to select the programming language?

Tags: programming-languages

I have a navigation providing interface, where in given the starting and destination points, and somehow the map of the street maybe, then the path is chosen based on the map, i.e. if a way is found then move in the direction, or if some blockage is found, or if the path will not lead to the desired destination then check for some other path maybe.

Now what programming language will be the best for it? I have worked with C only till now. Will it be all right for me to code in C only?

Is there anything else I need to take care before I take up this project? (Apart from the implementation issues).

Thanks.

Comment: When in doubt, choose intercal.

Comment: COBOL is the way to go. You can never go wrong with COBOL, you just need a blue tie to program in it.

Comment: Four sarcastic comments and counting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, the best thing to do is to just start coding and find out.  If you are not experienced, it's better to use the language you're familiar with rather than learn a new one.  At the end of the day, you can achieve most tasks with most languages.

It's not so much *what* you use but *how* you use it.

In terms of the path-finding implementation, you might want to start by looking at A-star or Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: The only modification I would make to this is that certain languages may not have good library support for certain tasks. For example, it's almost certainly easier to create a web service in Python than in C.

Comment: Yep, good point.  And I'm sure there are many libraries in a variety of languages that handle path-finding.  But there's something to be said for implementing an algorithm yourself.  As a new programmer, there's some basic grunt work you need to do before you start using libraries to do it for you.